# I want delete all the rows that matches specific column value in excel using vba but facing error

Tags: excel, vba, automationanywhere, excel-automation

```
Sub Delete_Rows()

Dim lo As ListObject 
Dim ActiveSheet As String
Dim wkbSource As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\nani\Desktop\11.0\deleteRows\abc.xlsx")

Set ActiveSheet = wkbSource.Sheets("LIST")

'perform delete

Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListOjects(1)

lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria:="" Or "claimed"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wkbSource.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the text of the error message, and on which line of code?

Comment: at line 7 saying compiler error: Oject required

Comment: Which is line7?

Comment: and also i want to check 2 more colums 13 and 14 and need to delete all rows satisfying all 3 columns conditions

Comment: line 7:  Set ActiveSheet = wkbSource.Sheets("LIST")

Comment: ActiveSheet should be declared as an object and not as a string

Answer (score 0):

Some fixes:

```
Sub Delete_Rows()

Dim lo As ListObject 
Dim ws As Worksheet '<<<<<<
Dim wkbSource As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\nani\Desktop\11.0\deleteRows\abc.xlsx")

Set ws = wkbSource.Sheets("LIST")

Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)  '<< typo

'fixed...
lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1 := "=", _
                           Operator := xlOr, _
                           Criteria2 := "claimed"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wkbSource.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it correct?


lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1 := "=", _
                           Operator := xlOr, _
                           Criteria2 := "claimed"

lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria3 := "=", _

lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1 := "=", _  ' <<<< if column value empty

Comment: There's no `Criteria3` - that should be `Criteria1`

Comment: line 9  Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)  '<< typo   error

Comment: subscript out of range

Comment: There's no listobject/table on that sheet?

Comment: we have header rows and columns

Comment: Is it an actual Table/ListObject though, or just a set of data?  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c

Comment: just a set of data with filter enabled on columns

Comment: ...but you can convert it to a table?  You need to do that if you want to use `DataBodyRange`

Comment: but i dono how much column range will be

Comment: i have an excel file in which we have 1 sheet with A to N columns.  I need to filter L columns with empty or "test" and M column not equal to empty and N column not equal to empty and delete all the rows satisfying above conditions

Comment: Did you try the code I posted?  You only need to convert your data into a Table

Comment: line 9 Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
subscript out of range  error